Как в Яндекс Диалоги (навыки Алисы) API сохранять данные пользователя?
Помогите с решением, нужно в навыке Яндекс Алисы, при запуске навыка первый раз, запросить и сохранить уникальный номер, который скажет пользователь. Далее при запуске навыка этот номер должен хранится в Яндекс Диалогах и у пользователя больше не запрашиваться. Смысл навыка - выдавать информацию из справочной базы, но только для конкретного пользователя, согласно его номеру-ID, который он сообщил ранее и навык его запомнил.
Основная проблема моего не понимания это то, как эти данные потом связывать с конкретным пользователем. Может быть по какому-то уникальному user_id от Яндекса... Правда Яндекс говорит, что этот id будет разный для одного пользователя если он зайдет с разных устройств...
